# Synchronizing Progress Database with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, data-synchronization, progress-db

I have a Progress Database OpenEdge 10.2A and we have SQL Server 2008R2. Now my requirement is to look for a tool that can do the database synchronization between these two databases (mentioned above).

Key features required are:

1. Data sync should be bi directional.
2. If one system is down then it should have the capability to store the updated data in itself, may be in form of message queue or something and then send to the destination when it is up.
3. Tool should be able to pick up the changes from the source as when any DML or DDL changes are done to the source system.
4. It should have the capability for the schedule data synchronization i.e. every schedule time the data sync should happen.

Could you please advise me what approach or any tool available in the market which could help in this?

Answer (score 0):

Progress has replication as an add on. But if that can handle Progress to MsSql or not I'm unsure.

Here is a link to **Progress 10.2B** documentation where you can read about replication among other things: 
http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-103525

10.2A is actually so old it's retired (released in 2008). Current version is 11.2. Anyway I think it would be a good idea for you to contact your local Progress office and ask if they have any solutions. http://www.progress.com

As for third party solutions, I haven't got a clue!

Answer (score 0):

Bravepoint has a "replicate to SQL" product. I have no experience with it though.

http://www.bravepoint.com/products-pro2-replication-suite.shtml

Comment: Ya Tim i knew about the tool but our company is not too keen on buying a tool, and its not a free one.

Comment: Then you're kind of stuck.